# How do I "shift" an entire website downward (vertically)?

Tags: html, css

I had a simple web design made for a client.

3 months later, the client wants a notification bar installed at the top. Easy. Hopped on to CodeCanyon and found a feasible script, saving me hours.

One major problem: The notification bar is overlayed on top of the webpage, instead of pushing the webpage downwards. The resulting effect is that the notification bar covers a part of the top logo, which is a big no-no.

Is there a simple way to just "shift" the entire web page design by, lets say 80px, without having to re-doing all the CSS?

Comment: Better add some code and the screenshot of the page. It would definitely help others to give proper suggestion.

Comment: if you separated head and content with a div, that should actually be quite easy. But as long as you do not provide some of the html structure you are using, it will be hard to help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a new <div> section just underneath the <body> tag with a height of 80px.  Give it any CSS styles you want and add the notification bar as child element of the <div>

Example.  Let's say this was your website:

```
<!doctype>
<html>
<body>
   Some existing content
</body>
</html>
```

Then adding the banner is easy:

```
<!doctype>
<html>
<body>
   <div style="height:80px;background:red;">Some div content. Put whatever controls you want here</div>
   Some existing content
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

One of the easyiest way is setting `margin-top` to `body`:

```
body {
    margin-top: 80px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood right this notification bar comes and goes, it's not permanently there...

If it's a CodeCanyon script it might have a callback method for when the script is fired. Just use that method (or the code you use to start the script) to set the wrapper of your entire page 80px below (like the answers before mine stated). And shrink it back when the script is finished (maybe a finished event method in the script?).

Another thing: It isn't good practice to mess with the body's paddings and margins. I would suggest to have a wrapping div around the whole page for this kind of situations.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap all your html data into a div:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <!-- html data -->
</div>
```

and set the margin-top for that element:

```
#wrapper {margin-top:80px;}
```